# Store DBContext Log in other EF table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ado.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to store all my logs in a DB table (imported with EF as well into my code).

My code looks like this:

```
public PMContext() :
        base("MYEntities")
    {
        Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;

        this.Database.Log = s => LogStore(s); 
    }

    private void LogStore(string message)
    {
        TLog log = new TLog();
        log.description = message;
        log.insertDate = DateTime.Now;
        Logs.Add(log);
        SaveChanges();
    }

public virtual DbSet<TLog> Logs { get; set; }
```

I cannot use SaveChanges() (get error "SqlConnection does not support parallel transactions") and if I remove that line nothing is stored in my db table.

How can I fix this?

Comment: You could override SaveChanges() http://www.softcodearticle.com/2013/07/entity-framework-auditing-implementation/

Answer (score 0):

I think this happens during a `SaveChanges` call anywhere in your app, because the SQL generated from this call is logged, which triggers a nested `SaveChanges` call that tries to start its own transaction.

And there is another thing: the `SaveChanges` call in your `LogStore` method will trigger logging itself, so you'd end up starting an infinite loop if it worked.

If you want to do this through a context, you better use a separate instance just for the logging. This instance itself should *not* do logging:

```
public PMContext() : this(true)
{ }

private PMContext(bool doLogging) : base("MYEntities")
{
    Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
    Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
    if (doLogging)
    {
        this.Database.Log = s => LogStore(s);
    }
}

private void LogStore(string message)
{
    using(var db = new PMContext(false))
    {
        TLog log = new TLog();
        log.description = message;
        log.insertDate = DateTime.Now;
        db.Logs.Add(log);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Probably its better to do this through async methods, because this synchronous execution affects all database interactions. But an even better option would be to do this through log4net, using its database logger.